# This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "". AND cannot find /usr/lib/qt5

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator

Ok so I've seen similar questions but none seem to provide a fix to my problem. I've been working on an application for several months now using Qt Creator and after using the application in root (for another unrelated project) I found I had several issues using Qt Creator related to permissions.

However once that issue was resolved I attempted to import my project that I had been developing on my Mac OS and now when I attempt to run the project I get the following error.

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this might be the case and no solution online seems to have an appropriate answer. If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say 'run the project' you mean compiling and running the executable? Or did you copy the executable and tried to run it?

Comment: I mean compiling and running the executable within the IDE

Comment: The next parts are just a guess, but things you could try: There is a qt-maintenance tool (basically the online installer; installed with the Qt package) where you can install/update different Qt library versions tools etc. Check there which library versions you have installed and if they match the compiler (at least on Win you need different ones for MSVC and mingw).

Comment: Perhaps check the `/usr/lib/qt5` folder, if there are files and a `platform` or `plugins` subfolder, or find it the installation directory of Qt. The question here is: are the necessary libs not installed or does the program just not find them (like in this case).

Comment: `xcb` looks like a linux dependency for the QtGUI. This should probably be `libqcocoa` on [macos](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html#application-dependencies). Here are some other hints on how to check dependecies (`otool`) of your binary and where to find them in the installation (similar/see comment above).

Comment: I am using a macbookpro however My main development OS (where the issue is) is linux GNOME 17.04. Also I have checked in /usr/lib/ and qt5 is not found there, which is odd since I have installed, reinstalled, removed and reinstalled several times and I'm pretty sure I've done it correctly (although admittedly I am apparently missing something)

I'll try the qt-maintanance tool but If its what I think your referring to then I have used it to remove qt (for reinstallation) and when looking for updates it gave me an error saying it required a repository

Comment: OK, I think I know the problem. You have to make sure, to delete ALL autogenerated files on the Mac (especiallybut not limited to: `make clean`, delete Makefiles and the 'appname.pro.user*' files). Explanation: These files contain information specific to your current development machine (OS, installed Qt, paths etc.). `make clean` does not delete all files to make a complete fresh setup, and qmake (generates Makefiles from `appname.pro`) can't/won't figure this out for you. If this works or gets you further, let me know. Then I can compile a real answer.

Comment: PS: with *all* files I mean *everything* that is not the project file itself or mentioned in the project file (headers, sources, resource config, resources, translations etc.). Perhaps make a backup first. If you have a seperate build directory, delete it, but also the mentioned `*pro.user* (should be in the source directory).

Comment: Oh my god I cant believe I didnt think of that OF COURSE the autogen files didnt work I was using a different OS!!! Thank you sooooooo much @LeBlue !

Comment: Glad I could help. I put together all findings into an answer, maybe you could accept it, to mark the question as closed.

Comment: Im not sure if I did it write but I did try and mark it answered

Answer (score 0):

`xcb` looks like a [linux](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html#qt-plugins) dependency for the QtGUI. This should probably be libqcocoa on [macos](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html#qt-plugins).

You have copied your Makefiles and other platform specific build files form linux to the macos system. These files contain information specific to your current development machine (OS, installed Qt, paths etc.). `make clean` does not delete all files to make a complete fresh setup, and `qmake` (generates Makefiles from `appname.pro`) can't/won't figure this out for you.

You have to make sure, to delete ALL autogenerated files on the Mac (especially but not limited to: `make clean`, delete `Makefiles` and the 'appname.pro.user*' files).

Afterwards a recompilation and running of the application should work, if you installed Qt on the macos correctly.